# how to check dynamically changing boolean value using three js

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, boolean

I'm making a 3D 4x4x4 tic tac toe with three js, and to check win combo condition, I created a boolean array. Since there are 16*4=64 blocks, I made a boolean array of size 64 and set it to false by default. And then whenever the user clicks one of the blocks it changes the clicked object to true dynamically. 
To check the horizontal win condition, i used this,

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, controls;
var targetList = [];
var targetListBool = new Array(64).fill(false);
console.log(targetListBool);

// var projector, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var projecter;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
  INTERSECTED;
init();
animate();

addCubes();
render();


function addCubes() {
  var xDistance = 30;
  var zDistance = 15;
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x6C70A8
  });

  //initial offset so does not start in middle.
  var xOffset = -80;
  //1
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xadc9f4
      }));
      mesh.position.x = (xDistance * (i)) + xOffset;
      mesh.position.z = (zDistance * (j));
      scene.add(mesh);
      targetList.push(mesh);
    }
    //2
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xadc9f4
      }));
      mesh2.position.x = (xDistance * (i)) + xOffset;
      mesh2.position.z = (zDistance * (j));
      mesh2.position.y = 15;
      scene.add(mesh2);
      targetList.push(mesh2);
    }
    //3
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xadc9f4
      }));
      mesh3.position.x = (xDistance * (i)) + xOffset;
      mesh3.position.z = (zDistance * (j));
      mesh3.position.y = 30;
      scene.add(mesh3);
      targetList.push(mesh3);
    }
    //4
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xadc9f4
      }));
      mesh4.position.x = (xDistance * (i)) + xOffset;
      mesh4.position.z = (zDistance * (j));
      mesh4.position.y = 45;
      scene.add(mesh4);
      targetList.push(mesh4);
    }
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < targetList.length; i++) {
    targetList[i].name = i;
  }

}




function init() {
  // Renderer.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  // renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add renderer to page
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Create camera.
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 150;


  // Add controls
  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
  controls.addEventListener('change', render);
  controls.target.set(0, 0, -50);

  // Create scene.
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

  // Create directional light and add to scene.
  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 100000);
  pointLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(pointLight);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  // Add listener for window resize.
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}


// initialize object to perform world/screen calculations
projector = new THREE.Projector();
// when the mouse moves, call the given function
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);


function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
  // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("Click.");

  // update the mouse variable
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  // find intersections

  // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
  //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
  projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
  ray.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(targetList);

  // if there is one (or more) intersections
  if (intersects.length > 0 && INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {


    INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
    INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
    console.log(INTERSECTED.name);

    // console.log("Hit @ " + toString( intersects[0].point ) );
    // change the color of the closest face.
    // intersects[ 0 ].face.color.setHex(0xffa500);
    // intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < targetList.length; i++) {

      if (INTERSECTED.name == i) {
        targetListBool[i] = true;

      }
    }
    console.log(targetListBool);
  }

}


// $(intersec).click(function(){
//   alert('you clicked number 1 block');
// });


function toString(v) {
  return "[ " + v.x + ", " + v.y + ", " + v.z + " ]";
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  controls.update();

}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  controls.handleResize();
}


for (let i = 0; i <targetListBool.length ; i+=4) {
  if(targetListBool[i]
  &&targetListBool[i+1]
  &&targetListBool[i+2]
  &&targetListBool[i+3]){
      alert('win');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tic tac toe</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Monospace;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      margin: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .info {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.8;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .info a {
      color: #00ffff;
    }
    
    button {
      display: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <!-- <button id="restart">Restart</button> -->
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r84/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to check just horizontal win combination for a starter now.

```
 for (let i = 0; i <targetListBool.length ; i+=4) {
  if(targetListBool[i]
  &&targetListBool[i+1]
  &&targetListBool[i+2]
  &&targetListBool[i+3]){
      alert('win');
  }
```

}

But it doesn't know that some values have changed by click event earier.
Just to clarify, it's supposed to alert 'win' if 4 consecutive horizontal blocks are clicked in each plane. but I guess something's wrong with the if statement in the for loop at the end of the snippet.

It's my first time using three js and i'm not really familiar with javaScript either. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please can you add your html file and create a snippet within the SO question.

Comment: _"Since there are 16*4=52 blocks"_ O_o 16 * 4 = 64. I insist :)

Comment: Your snippet works for me.

Comment: @LloydNicholson I put the code snippet, thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaijens Really? It's supposed to alert 'win' but It's not..! I managed to turn the clicked element in the array to true with event but that's where i'm stuck..

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks, i corrected it.

Comment: @JessicaKim wel the log showed on value on true so the array is correct.But when you make an horizontal line you got 4 booleans on true bit the are not after eachother. Thats why your check fails. Better to move away from the standard array and use some kind of method to track them in a 3d way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system wins if it has 4 in a row on either the x,y or z axis. Your function only check the booleans in one direction. So best is to track the data in a 3 dimensional way. Here is an example of it. I manually set 4 on a row on the z axis and then do the check.

The check could and should be improved though. It's pretty inefficient, but kept it easy for the example and because I don't know your exact intentions. Should diagonals be checked too for example?

```js
//Fill a variable with x,y,z coordinates with a boolean value that is false.
var locations = {};

for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
  locations[x] = {};
  for (var y = 1; y <= 4; y++) {
    locations[x][y] = {};
    for (var z = 1; z <= 4; z++) {
      locations[x][y][z] = false;
    }
  }
}

//Set 4 values on the X axis to true for testing
locations[1][2][3] = true;
locations[2][2][3] = true;
locations[3][2][3] = true;
locations[4][2][3] = true;

//Set 4 values on the Z axis to true for testing
locations[1][2][1] = true;
locations[1][2][2] = true;
locations[1][2][3] = true;
locations[1][2][4] = true;


//Test if there are 4 on a row - note this can be done more efficient with a bit more thought and does not work for diagonals
var winX = false;
var winY = false;
var winZ = false;
for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
  for (var y = 1; y <= 4; y++) {
    for (var z = 1; z <= 4; z++) {
      if(locations[x][y][z]) {
        //check X for current position
        if(locations[1][y][z] && locations[2][y][z] && locations[3][y][z] && locations[4][y][z]) {
          winX = true;
        }
        //check Y for current position
        if(locations[x][1][z] && locations[x][2][z] && locations[x][3][z] && locations[x][4][z]) {
          winY = true;
        }
        //check Z for current position
        if(locations[x][y][1] && locations[x][y][2] && locations[x][y][3] && locations[x][y][4]) {
          winZ = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//Log the results, should return true for X and Z and false for Y
console.log("Win X: " + winX);
console.log("Win Y: " + winY);
console.log("Win Z: " + winZ);
```

Comment: Changed array to object to fix a bug with the array indexing and to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I got my issue fixed, it was bc the win combo checker was not in the click function. Thanks for the 3d array idea tho, i will definitely change my code into 3d arrays!